# centos: unable to write to whoosh indexes

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, python, django

got a problem here. In my development server, I ran into a problem when I try to search using `django`/`haystack` with the `whoosh` backend engine.

```
The path to your Whoosh index '/home/foo/bar/whoosh/index' is not writable for the current user/group.
```

Hmm this seems like a obvious permissions problem, but when I check my folder

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 foodball django 4096 Apr 27 03:17 index
```

it seems correct, as the user `apache` is added to the group `django`. May I know what seems to be the problem, is `apache` not the user the process is running under?

Comment: What are the permissions on /home/foo/bar/whoosh ?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx  3 foodball django    4096 Apr 27 03:17 whoosh/

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Was that resolved? if yes, what was the soluton?

Answer (score 0):

If SELinux is enabled, it might cause the error. If you don't need SELinux or just quickly want to test if it's the reason, try command `setenforce 0` and see if that helped. SELinux can be permanently disabled by setting it to `disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config`.

Comment: couldn't find the command nor the file /etc/selinux/config.

Comment: do i have to create one myself??

Comment: Then you either are not using the server as root or you don't have SELinux installed at all.

Comment: hmmm o+w is fine though...